# using service bus messageReceiver CompleteAsync

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have an azure function that uses a service bus trigger:

```
        public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger()] string message,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(message);           
            await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(OrchestratorFunction), response);            
        }
```

I need to update this to:

```
        public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger()] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {            
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));           
            var res = starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(OrchestratorFunction), response);
            await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
            await res (what do I update this line to?)                        
        }
```

Comment: You can refer to [Use batching in MessageReceiver.RegisterMessageHandler](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/582#issue-366865527), [Handling service bus messages in Durable Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279051/handling-service-bus-messages-in-durable-functions) and [Service Bus –Complete Message Asynchronously or Synchronously?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/service-bus-complete-message-asynchronously-or-synchronously/ba-p/2073742)

Answer (score 0):

You can use start the orchestration with **Await**

```cs
# here you can get the Instance ID.
 var res = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(OrchestratorFunction), response);

# so you can skip this part(You don't want to await the Instance ID )
await res (what do I update this line too?)
```

I have modified the code at the end which resembles completing the **Async operation** started in the **Orchestrator function**.

```cs
      public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger()] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {            
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));  

            # here you can get the Instance ID.         
            var res = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(OrchestratorFunction), response);

          
            # It Completes the message and it will not receive again.
            await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

            # This can be done only if the MessageReceiver is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
            await messageReceiver.CloseAsync();

            # skip this part it won't required because while calling the StartNewAsync we call the await.
            //await res (what do I update this line too?)                        
        }
```

If you want to get the status of your orchestrator function you can use the **await starter.GetStatusAsync(< orchestration instanceId>);**. After the asynchronous operation of the orchestration client which means after the code of **await starter.StartNewAsync()**.

```cs
var orchestrationStatus = await starter.GetStatusAsync(<orchestration instanceId>);
var status = orchestrationStatus.RuntimeStatus.ToString().ToUpper();
 
while (status == "PENDING" || status == "RUNNING")
{
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     orchestrationStatus = await starter.GetStatusAsync(<  orchestration instanceId>);
     status = orchestrationStatus.RuntimeStatus.ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

Refer [here](https://ajitpatra.com/2020/01/15/using-service-bus-triggered-azure-durable-function-with-d365-ce/) for more information